# Trying to identify an IC labeled 5AF2S

Tags: integrated-circuit

I'm trying to repair a laptop motherboard for a coworker and found a shorted IC.
I'm not sure of what it is so i'd like to know if anyone could give me an hint

The IC is labeled 5AF2S and is in SOC70-5 package.

I found out it could be a 3 state non inverting buffer but I'm really not sure.

The motherboard part number is byg43 nm-a601

Edit:
Here is a picture i had in my phone.
The red circle is the ic try to identify
The green circle is something that is gone too ( it only hangs on one leg and show marks of corrosion )

[image]

Edit more picture
[image]

This last one is the green circled part of the first picture
Marking is FAL CO it is a zener diode DFLZ5V6-7 
[image]

Edit: I just bought the schematic
It is a power distribution switch G517F2T11U
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1912111437_GMT-Global-Mixed-mode-Tech-G517F2T11U_C356801.pdf

Comment: How do you know it's shorted if you don't know its type?

Comment: Could you add two photos - one showing the area it is in, and another a close-up?

Comment: Because it's a non starting lapto, and by just puling the power supply, this specific component draws something like 1.5w (0.5A@3.3V), making it burning hot. I should have specified it is seems to be shorted to ground.
@rdtsc I'll takes pictures tonight when i returns home

Answer (score 2):

The ic is a power distribution switch G517F2T11U https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1912111437_GMT-Global-Mixed-mode-Tech-G517F2T11U_C356801.pdf

The diode is a zener diode DFLZ5V6-7